General catch in Masstransit
How to write general catch that catch all exceptions in the consume (in the filter and in normal process) and then will return to the client proper response that contain properties of the exception? I tried a lot of code, but all of them catch the exceptions after the exceptions came to the client, so it was ineffective.
This is my code:
startup.cs:
services.AddMassTransit(config => { 
     config.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<ConsumersLst>();

     config.AddBus(context => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(c =>
     {
        {
             UseConsumeFilter(c, typeof(MyConsumeFilter<>), context);

             c.Host("rabbitmq://10.10.10.10:5672/", h =>
             {
                 h.Password("guest");
                 h.Username("guest");
             });

            c.ConfigureEndpoints(context, KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance);
         } 
      }));
    });


public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<FullRequest<REQ>> context)
{
     var req = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte[])context.ReceiveContext.GetBody());
     REQ checkTzStudentAndParentQuery = mapper.Map<REQ>(context.Message.appData);

     var res = await mediator.Send(req);
     await context.RespondAsync<FullResponse<RES>>(res);  
 }

